# Python: get folder chain from path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following path as an input:

```
path = "D:\dataset\raw\2018\fk180731\tuna_sand\20180805_215810_ts_un6k\image\i20180805_215810"
```

and I want to create the same folder chain in the directory of my script. I want the new folder chain to start from the "raw" folder.
for example:

```
D:\MY_SCRIPT_LOCATION\raw\2018\fk180731\tuna_sand\20180805_215810_ts_un6k\image\i20180805_215810
```

I have tried

```
head_tail = os.path.split(path)
print(head_tail[1])
```

But this only gives me the name of the last folder. Any idea how to do this?

thanks

To clarify: I want the script to edit the input path and remove everything comes before "raw". Then use the current directory of the script to create the folder chain starting from "raw"

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to replace `dataset` by `MY_SCRIPT_LOCATION` and the rest of the path should be unchanged?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to replace anything comes before raw to be replaced by the script location

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print path, use `print(path.replace('dataset','MY_SCRIPT_LOCATION'))`

If you want to create folders as new path use the following code:

```
import os
path = 'D:\\dataset\\raw\\2018\\fk180731\\tuna_sand\\20180805_215810_ts_un6k\\image\\i20180805_215810'
path = path.replace('dataset','MY_SCRIPT_LOCATION')
print(path)
try:
    os.makedirs(path)
except:
    print('Cannot create a file when that file already exists')
print('Done')
```

Comment: it's not just about printing the path. I want to create that path within the script location

Comment: My mistake for not making it clear. but the input path doesnt always have to be the same. It could be something like
D:\dataset\folder1\folder2\raw\2018\fk180731\tuna_sand\20180805_215810_ts_un6k\image\i20180805_215810

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot. Please check now

Comment: If you want to get user input use: `path = input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import os
path='D:/dataset/raw/2018/fk180731/tuna_sand/20180805_215810_ts_un6k/image/i20180805_215810'
a=path.split('/')
a.pop(0)
a.pop(0)

new_path='D:/MY_SCRIPT_LOCATION/'+'/'.join(a)
os.makedirs(new_path)
print('success')
```